# Give default value to Select Field in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having the following Select Field :

```
    <SelectField
      id={quesId}
      required
      menuItems={opts}
      style={style.selectionStyle}
      className="md-cell"
      defaultValue = {value}
    />
```

Here, opts is an array of objects:

```
    opts = [{id: "1", value: "1", label: "DL"},
            {id: "2", value: "2", label: "UP"},
            {id: "3", value: "3", label: "PB"},
            {id: "4", value: "4", label: "MH"},
            {id: "5", value: "5", label: "WB"},
            {id: "6", value: "6", label: "KN"},
            {id: "7", value: "7", label: "GJ"},
            {id: "8", value: "8", label: "RJ"},
            {id: "9", value: "9", label: "BR"},
            {id: "10", value: "10", label: "TN"},
            {id: "11", value: "11", label: "AP"},
            {id: "12", value: "12", label: "TN"}]
```

What I want to do is set the default value of my select field as "AP" for which i am passing value which is

```
    value = {id: "11", value: "11", label: "AP"}
```

The problem here is that The default value of select field is not set. Not getting what to do. Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to show the code for the component, we can't know what the `defaultValue` prop is doing

Comment: @DarrenSweeney Which code you are asking for ?

Comment: Is SelectFields a custom component or something from a Library.

Comment: The code which creates `<SelectField />`

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Yes I am using this component from a library.

Comment: Which library, can you please mention that

Comment: @DarrenSweeney I have already shared the code for select field

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I am using the select filed from react-md.mlaursen.com

Answer (score 0):

Is this you need to achieve ?

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-fycqzp)

Assign select value from state like below :

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleLangSelect = this.handleLangSelect.bind(this);
    this.state =  {
      "lang_selected": "English"
    };
  }

  handleLangSelect(event) {
      this.setState({lang_selected:event.target.value});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <select className="form-control" id="langSelect" value={this.state.lang_selected} onChange={this.handleLangSelect}>
            <option>Others</option>
            <option>French</option>
            <option>English</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

As per the [Docs](https://react-md.mlaursen.com/components/select-fields?tab=1#select-field-proptypes-default-value) says, the value should match one of the menu item's `itemValue` or be the empty string.

So you can set it as:

```
<SelectField
  id={quesId}
  required
  menuItems={opts}
  style={style.selectionStyle}
  className="md-cell"
  defaultValue={opts[10].value}
/>
```